# HTTPS source code has whitespace, but HTTP doesn't

Tags: html, css, apache, symfony, https

My problem is that the odd element on a site looks different when I view it using a HTTPS connection. When viewing source I've found that the https pages have some additional line breaks and white space etc. I need both to be the same. As an example, all tooltip icons in my nav bar have additional line breaks when I view a https page so they can be seen to visible jump left and right as you change pages - all because of the line breaks and whitespace.

According to the Chrome web inspector both http and https pages are being gzipped.

Can someone point me to a few things to investigate as I can't think?

Also, this may happen on other sites too. If you view the source of http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/ and https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/ then you can see additional line breaks. Neither the HTTP or HTTPS version is gzipped for that site though.

I'm sure an option would be to change the CSS/HTML but it's actually not really bad CSS/HTML and it would be so much easier if both HTTP/HTTPS did the same without having to add this extra check every time I write CSS/HTML.

I'm using Symfony2 (I have tested that this still happens outside the framework) so maybe I could get that to compress all whitespace instead. I have used the {% spaceless %} tag in my parent Twig template, but it doesn't remove all whitespace and it seems too much hassle to keep using these kind of tags.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Added image.

[image: side-by-side HTTP v HTTPS in Chrome]

Comment: By line break you mean `\n` or `<br/>`?

Comment: `wget http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/` and `wget https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/` give exactly the same file, byte by byte. Where are you seeing the line breaks?

Comment: I don't know what a 'wget' is, but when viewing in a web browser and selecting to view source I can clearly see the differences. The site mentioned is a good example as it accepts a https request on that page, where some don't for the same URL.

Comment: As for line break, I mean \n, but also whitespace as well. Thanks

Comment: @user2143356 If the files show up different in the browser, then it seems to be the browser's doing, not the server's. Which browser are you using? Can't see any difference at all when viewing source in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, but I've added the image of what I see in Chrome (Mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

The network connection I'm using is compressing pages by removing line breaks from every site I visit (including the one I'm having an issue with as well as the AWS site example), but only does this on non-secure pages.

Adding a 'no-transform' cache-control header prevents this from happening.

Comment: A network connection cannot "remove line breaks". Maybe it's a server module or a proxy setting: I suggest to act on that, rather than working around in HTTP headers. Anyway, markup should not depend on line breaks and spaces, consider restructuring it.

Comment: No, it does remove all the line breaks. They do it to reduce load on the network. It also compresses some images (and injects some JS so you can hold certain keys to reload those images). The markup issue is simply pressing enter in my text editor. All HTML on every web page appears on literally one line with my network connection as it is, but they obviously can't edit SSL requests, hence the 1px difference on the odd occasion.